# React App page refreshes to the wrong page after posting data to a Postgres database on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, heroku

**1. Summarize the problem**

GitHub repo: https://github.com/JorySmith/feature-request-tracker

GitHub live project: https://jorysmith.github.io/feature-request-tracker/

This is a simple feature tracker app with the React front-end deployed on GitHub pages and Node/Postgress back-end deployed on Heroku.

After I type in a new feature description in the input field and click 'Add', the new feature request is properly posted into my Heroku Postgres database. However, the page refreshes to 'https://jorysmith.github.io/' and I get a 404 error, "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."

The same issue happens for editing and deleting features already in the database. The PUT, POST, and DELETE work in changing the database as needed, but the page refreshses to 'https://jorysmith.github.io/'

[Image of feature tracker app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klxmB.jpg)

**2. Describe what you’ve tried**

I added a `e.preventDefault` and `window.location = '/'` to the onSubmitForm function:

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const InputFeature = () => {

  const [description, setDescription] = useState("")

  const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = { description }
      const response = await fetch("https://feature-request-tracker-api.herokuapp.com", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      })
      window.location = '/'
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Feature Request Tracker</h1>
      <h3 className="text-center mt-1">A React CRUD App</h3>
      <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={description} onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
        <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  )

}

export default InputFeature
```

I also changed my endpoints for GET and POST to just '/', and for PUT and DELETE to '/:id':

```js
// Add a feature request
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { description } = req.body
    const newFeature = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO featurerequest (description) VALUES ($1) RETURNING *",
      [description]
    )
    res.json(newFeature.rows[0])
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
  }

})

// Get one feature request
app.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const feature = await pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM featurerequest WHERE feature_id = $1",
      [id])

    res.json(feature.rows[0])

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
  }
})

// Update one feature request
app.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params
    const { description } = req.body
    const updateFeature = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE featurerequest SET description = $1 WHERE feature_id = $2",
      [description, id]
    )

    res.json("Feature was updated.")

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
  }
})

// Delete one feature request
app.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params
    const deleteFeature = await pool.query(
      "DELETE FROM featurerequest WHERE feature_id = $1",
      [id]
    )
    res.json("Feature was deleted.")

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
  }
})
```

Comment: in package.json did you add your subdirectory name like - "homepage": "/feature-request-tracker/" - can you try this

Comment: Thank you. I tried `"homepage": "/feature-request-tracker"` and `"homepage": "https://jorysmith.github.io/feature-request-tracker/"` for the front end package.json file. Both didn't work for me.

Comment: ok did you include - <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/"> in public/index.html file header?

Comment: I just added <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/"> in public/index.html file head. I'm still getting redirected to the wrong page, unfortunately.

Comment: found the issue.. let me give you an answer

Comment: if you open this url https://jorysmith.github.io/feature-request-tracker/index.html it's blank because resources are getting failed with wrong path.

Comment: can you add %PUBLIC_URL%/feature-request-tracker/ in public/index.html wherever it's used.

Comment: I updated %PUBLIC_URL%/feature-request-tracker/ in public/index.html wherever it's used. The input submit is still refreshing to "https://jorysmith.github.io/" instead of "https://jorysmith.github.io/feature-request-tracker/"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lakshman, who pointed out to add to my index.html:

```
<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
```

I also had to change `window.location = '/'` to `window.location = '/feature-request-tracker/'` wherever it was used.